# How to open database connection through hostinger

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to use C# to connect to my database which is being hosted at; https://www.hostinger.com/ . I do not know which server hostname I should use. I can't connect since I do not know what to use for the server hostname.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplicationName
{
    class Database
    {
        public static string connstring = "server=serverhostname;database=dbname;uid=dbuser;password=dbpass;";

        public static void CheckConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connstring;

                conn.Open();

                MessageBox.Show("Connection Checked: Success", "WindowsApplicationName");
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Checked: Failed", "WindowsApplicationName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from [PasteBin](https://www.pastebin.com/nS6f3zLw). Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0. Attributed to "a guest" posted there on 2019-01-02.

I tried using their server hostname on the Remote MySQL: sql164.main-hosting.eu,
Also tried: mysql.hostinger.com,
Also tried: my ip

Connection failed, it said; "Database credentials are wrong or *something"

Comment: either look up their document or ask their support for "MySQL connection string"

Comment: Post your code here (with the proper formating), not as a link to an external website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this article https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql the server name may look like mysql.hostinger.com, the database name should look like u266072517_name. You need a correct username and password, too. They offer online chat, you should give it a try. You can test the database access with tools like Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or similar.